# GCKDiscoveryManager not founding Chromecast devices iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, google-cast

I'm trying to find Chromecast devices with my iOS App.

I've downloaded cast SDK via CocoaPods, and then I try the following:

```
let gckCastOptions = GCKCastOptions(receiverApplicationID: kGoogleCastAppReceiverId)
        GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWithOptions(gckCastOptions)
        GCKLogger.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        self.discoveryManager = GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().discoveryManager
        self.discoveryManager!.addListener(self)
        self.discoveryManager!.passiveScan = true
        self.discoveryManager!.startDiscovery()
```

And then, in the listener method:

```
func didStartDiscoveryForDeviceCategory(deviceCategory: String) {
        print("GCKDiscoveryManagerListener: \(deviceCategory)")

        print("FOUND: \(self.discoveryManager!.hasDiscoveredDevices)")
    }
```

Result is always false :(

On my Mac, when I open YouTube, I can stream video to Chromecast device, so device is set definitely.

I am testing on simulator? Should I try it on real device? I suppose that this is not necessary since I'm only trying to discover the available devices.

I've tried to add `GCKDeviceScanner` too, no luck. I suppose that this is the starting point.

Tried to add `GCKUICastButton` via storyboard - not being able to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this setting. As soon as I enabled it it started working

[image]

Also, please make sure you set another kReceiverAppID other than the given example (AABBCCDD), for example we are using the one listed on the example app, for example static NSString *const kReceiverAppID = @"4F8B3483" (I guess you need to make your own at Google Play Developer Console)

And finally, you can be pretty sure it will never work on a simulator, you need REAL device for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alejandro. I will test it on my device. However, can you please tell me - I'm always using Google Developer Console, for Google Maps, Google Places API, etc. But when I try to use it for Google Cast, it is asking for a payment info. Is this correct or does it have the free version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have registered in Google Cast Developer Console. Strange thing is that there are only receiver types. Strange - I want to stream from iPhone to Chromecast device. Isn't that Sender app? How can I register sender app? Also, I've registered my TV as a device in Developer Console, and now I am testing on real device, but in that print - it still says FOUND: false.

Comment: Yes, that's true, xD $5 for each app

Comment: Any idea on: No cast_nearby_client_auth found in application keychain - will request from server.

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that, did not see on my development

Comment: @Djuro : do note that it does work for Simulator, you just need to be on same network

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in this setting. Go to project capabilities

[image]

Go to project setting and select device capabilities. select this option as discussed in image

Comment: Please include all the relevant bits of the linked page in your answer. Otherwise there is a risk that external content is changed or removed, and your answer will become useless.